# create nested dictionary or collection counter with pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, counter

I would like to create a nested dictionary or Collection in python by grouping

```
seriesA = ["groupA", "groupA", "groupB", "groupB", "groupC"]
seriesB = ["item1", "item1," "item3", "item1", "item2"]
```

Desired output:

```
{ 'groupA': {'item1': 2},
  'groupB': {'item3': 1}, {'item1':1},
  'groupC': {'item2': 1}}
```

In Python, is there an easier way or would I iterate through the listed tuples, and add a collection counter?

```
nested_dict["groupA"]["item1"]
```

...should return 2 occurrences.

Comment: That's an invalid dictionary

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have `'groupB': {'item3': 1, 'item1':1},` in the desired output?

Comment: What would it be called? A dictionary with a nested key-value pair, or with a counter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `collections.defaultdict` and `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from pprint import pprint

seriesA = ["groupA", "groupA", "groupB", "groupB", "groupC"]
seriesB = ["item1", "item1", "item3", "item1", "item2"]

nested_dict = defaultdict(Counter)

for a,b in zip(seriesA, seriesB):
    nested_dict[a][b] += 1

assert nested_dict["groupA"]["item1"] == 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the format should be  `{key:[{ke1:va1,key2:val2}]}`

```
pd.DataFrame([seriesA,seresB]).T.groupby([0,1]).size().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : [x.reset_index(level=0,drop=True).to_dict()]).to_dict()
Out[362]: 
{'groupA': [{'item1': 2}],
 'groupB': [{'item1': 1, 'item3': 1}],
 'groupC': [{'item2': 1}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output, as specified, is not a valid dictionary. However, you can get a similar valid result using `itertools.groupby` and `collections.Counter`:

```
seriesA = ["groupA", "groupA", "groupB", "groupB", "groupC"]
seriesB = ["item1", "item1", "item3", "item1", "item2"]

from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

myCounts = {k: Counter(map(lambda g: g[1], group)) 
 for k, group in groupby(sorted(zip(seriesA, seriesB)), key=lambda x: x[0])}

print(myCounts)
#{'groupA': Counter({'item1': 2}),
# 'groupB': Counter({'item1': 1, 'item3': 1}),
# 'groupC': Counter({'item2': 1})}
```

If you didn't want to have `Counter`s in your dictionary, you could convert them using:

```
print({k: dict(v) for k, v in myCounts.items()})
#{'groupA': {'item1': 2},
# 'groupB': {'item1': 1, 'item3': 1},
# 'groupC': {'item2': 1}}
```

Comment: Maybe `groupby(sorted(zip(...)), key=...)`. That way the code works regardless of the order of `seriesA`.